# Sub menus in Wordpress site closes unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu

Please check the given URL : https://www.just-airsoftguns.com/

Since I am not very experienced developer, I need help to create the above site into mobile responsive site.
Also, when I inspect and check menu, it does not work properly. The sub menu closes unexpectedly.
I want to fix it, if any one can guide, would be great help.

**I just found out that after deactiv
ating Woocommerce plugin, the mobile menu is working fine.**

Comment: I am using wordpress and I did not do any specific coding to fix that.Which file do you want me to share?

Comment: I am using ready made theme - Blade theme.